# Who gets the funds raised by tariffs levied at the edges of the European Customs Union?

Tags: european-union, taxes

The European Union Customs Union has a Common External Tariff.

A tax on imports.

Who is the recipient of the funds raised by this tax?

A country outside of the European Union Customs Union may levy its own tariffs and be in receipt of the funds raised.

By joining the EU does a state forfeit control of its share of these funds?

Comment: Nice question. I suppose it is the country goods are shipped into who is responsible for raising tariffs and will keep the funds, but I've no source to document that hypothesis.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Who is the recipient of the funds raised by this tax?

The EU is the [ultimate recipient](http://ec.europa.eu/budget/explained/budg_system/financing/fin_en.cfm#own_res) of custom duties, after the country that collects it retains 20% of the amount to cover its collection costs.

> By joining the EU does a state forfeit control of its share of these funds?

Yes, except for the above mentioned collection costs bit.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what percentage contribution these taxes make to EU income?

Comment: @Ben: 13.9% in 2016, including sugar levies (together called _traditional own resources_). http://ec.europa.eu/budget/figures/interactive/index_en.cfm

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised the loss of control of this large income stream was never mentioned by the Leave side in the referendum.

Comment: @Ben: That's because it's not a large income stream.

Comment: It was €144 billion in 2016. I am not sure if this includes sugar levies and agricultural duties. (Source: http://ec.europa.eu/budget/figures/interactive/index_en.cfm)

Comment: @Ben: Right. But that's across the EU, not specifically for the UK - and knowing the UK [barely even registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_ports_in_Europe) among the busiest ports in Europe. It's epsilon compared to, say, how much it cost the UK to bail out its banks a decade ago.

Comment: UK sourced funds are ~€3.9 billion/annum (2016). The bank bailout does not change the magnitude of this value. That is 40% of our net “membership fee” that there was so much heat about during the referendum.

Comment: @Ben to suggest that the UK could generate revenue from collecting import duties after leaving the EU would run counter to new free trade agreements mantra of the leave campaign and Brexiteer positions. To simultaneously suggest that being in the EU prevents the UK from engaging in "free trade" and that leaving the EU would allow the UK to keep increased customs revenue, i.e. the trade barrier monies, might have been a contradiction too far.